# Pause video in Slick slider when slide is changed

Tags: jquery, video, wordpress-theming, slick.js

I have a 2-slide carousel using Slick, each slide contains a video, which is pulled from a custom (ACF) media field in Wordpress (hosted files, not embeds from YouTube). If I hit play on one video, and then navigate to the next slide, that video keeps playing, so we still hear the sound.

It makes sense that it would do this, but it's not what I need it to do. When changing slides, I'd like to pause all videos.

Here's what I have.

Html:

```
<div class="project-carousel">
 <div class="slidewrap">
  <div class="slide">
   <div class="leftcol">
    <div style="width: 640px;" class="wp-video"><!--[if lt IE 9]><script>document.createElement('video');</script><![endif]-->
     <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-220-1" width="640" height="360" poster="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/ChloeRosser_Breath1.png" preload="metadata" controls="controls"><source type="video/mp4" src="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Breath-1.mp4?_=1" /><a href="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Breath-1.mp4">https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Breath-1.mp4</a></video>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="rightcol">
    <ul class="nostyle nopad mid-grey">
     <li class="dark-grey">Breath 1</li>
     <li class="small">2018</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="slidewrap">
  <div class="slide">
   <div class="leftcol">
    <div style="width: 640px;" class="wp-video">
     <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-220-2" width="640" height="360" poster="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/ChloeRosser_Breath2.png" preload="metadata" controls="controls"><source type="video/mp4" src="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Breath-2.mp4?_=2" /><a href="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Breath-2.mp4">https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Breath-2.mp4</a></video>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="rightcol">
    <ul class="nostyle nopad mid-grey">
     <li class="dark-grey">Breath 2</li>
     <li class="small">2018</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.project-carousel').slick({
 speed: 500,
 fade: true,
 cssEase: 'linear',
});
```

The whole thing can be viewed [here](https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/project/breath/). This is client artwork and may be considered NSFW if rules are very strict.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you access the mediaelement js object from where your slick script is?

Comment: @joshmoto in all honesty, i don't know. how do i find out? i'm implementing slick.js as per ken's instructions – [link](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: How you implementing you video? Just with HTML and a class? Did you install mediaelement js? You could use another library like video js https://videojs.com/ which would be easier to do what your saying.

Comment: @joshmoto this is all being done via wordpress so i am calling the video from the site's media library using the shortcode `<?php echo do_shortcode('[video src="'.$url.'"]'); ?>` after fetching variables (url, title etc) via php. what i posted above is the resulting html. i suspect i don't already have the access you mean – i'm not familiar with the resources you mention.

Comment: From what I can tell your video player is using this http://www.mediaelementjs.com/, is the `$url` the path to your video? I could build you a new short code to called `[videojs src="'.$url.'"]` but you would have to load in video js. Before you do this lets try something. Is this slick code above your entire slick function?

Comment: yes `$url` is the path to the video, and the above code is the whole slick function. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just take this slick script from the demo below and replace your slick script.

Then click the arrow on your site change slide and let me know what the `console.log` results are.

Read the comments in my slick script so you know what is going on.

```js
// project carousel slick options
$('.project-carousel').slick({
  speed: 500,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear'

  // before slide change  
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  // current slide
  let slide = $('[data-slick-index="' + currentSlide + '"]', this);

  // find video in this slide by mediaelementwrapper
  let video = $('MEDIAELEMENTWRAPPER > VIDEO', slide);

  // if we have a video in this slide
  if (video.length) {

    // please send me what this outputs on your site when you click next slide
    // we might be able to hook into the mediaelementjs object from here and pause the video
    console.log(video);
    
    // also uncomment this and try this
    // $(video).paused = true;

  }

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="project-carousel">
  <div class="slide">
    <div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container wp-video-shortcode mejs-video">
      <div class="mejs-inner">
        <div class="mejs-mediaelement">
          <mediaelementwrapper id="video-220-1">
            <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-220-1_html5" width="640" height="360" poster="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/ChloeRosser_Breath1.png" preload="metadata" src="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Breath-1.mp4?_=1"
              style="width: 478.156px; height: 268.963px;"></video>
          </mediaelementwrapper>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div id="mep_1" class="mejs-container wp-video-shortcode mejs-video">
      <div class="mejs-inner">
        <div class="mejs-mediaelement">
          <mediaelementwrapper id="video-220-2">
            <video class="wp-video-shortcode" id="video-220-1_html5" width="640" height="360" poster="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/ChloeRosser_Breath1.png" preload="metadata" src="https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Breath-1.mp4?_=1"
              style="width: 478.156px; height: 268.963px;"></video>
          </mediaelementwrapper>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    Slide 3
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks so much – i think i've implemented this correctly, but so far i'm not seeing a change in behaviour. i'm assuming that the differences in our html are just structural and won't affect the result. i have console logs for performance with and without the `$(video).paused = true;` line uncommented – what is the correct way to show you these? i've also updated                 the code [at the staging site](https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/project/breath/).

Comment: addition: this code _has_ prevented more than one video playing at once. the videos still keep playing when the slide changes though.

Comment: Really, this shouldn't change anything. All we are doing is `console.log`. Do you mean this `$(video).paused = true;` is preventing video. Can I see, have you got it running now on site?

Comment: thanks so much for sticking with me on this. unless i'm mistaken (which is more than possible), the staging site i linked to above has your code implemented, directly after the slick function. [take a look here](https://cro.matmartin.co.uk/project/breath/). it's definitely changed something, because it's removed all the CSS styling i had in place, too.

Comment: In what file, I can't seem to find where it is? Is this slick implementation part of the theme or have you built slick into it? Styling looks ok in the last link you sent.

Comment: I see you are firing slick twice on the same element. https://i.imgur.com/BAyQfdz.png - just replace your slick script with mine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224051/discussion-between-joshmoto-and-mtm).

Comment: of course you're right – i meant to fire only on video-based carousels but doubled up my classes for styling. will fix that and chat in, thanks.